# KQL Kusto renaming multiple colums with one project-rename

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

When i use summarize any() all my columns get a new name any_original name.
I want to keep the original name or rename the any away

in Splunk used to do something like
rename value(*) as *
and that did the trick, in kql im not sure

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bRpU.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ORIGINAL ANSWER (May 2021)**

You can supply your own column names, like this:

```
MyTable
| summarize (Timestamp, Api, Application) = any(Timestamp, Api, Application)
```

**UPDATE (Jun 2021)**

Following your request, we've introduced a new aggregation function, called `take_any()` that behaves just like `any()`, but leaves the column names as is:

For example:

```
MyTable
| summarize take_any(Timestamp, Api, Application)
```

The output will contain 3 columns named: Timestamp, Api, Application.

Comment: That is super helpfull, but is there a more "lazy" way ?
something like 
| summarize (*) = any(Timestamp, Api, Application)

That preserve all original column names = Timestamp, Api, Application

Comment: Nope - you have to provide the column names explicitly.

Comment: Following your request, we've introduced a new aggregation function, called `take_any()` that behaves just like `any()`, but leaves the column names as is. I've updated the answer accordingly.